# Simplifying algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am doing a problem where I am differentiating from first principles, but I can't simplify the final expression:

$\frac{-2xh - h^2}{x^4h + 2x^3h^2+x^2h^3}$

Could someone explain it in steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $$\frac{-2x-h}{x^2(x^2+2xh+h^2)}=\frac{-2x-h}{x^2(x+h)^2}$$
it must be $$x\ne 0,x\ne -h$$
If $$h$$ tends to zero we obtain $$\frac{-2x}{x^2(x^2)}=\frac{-2x}{x^4}=\frac{-2}{x^3}$$

Comment: Could you explain what would happen to the equation if h tends to 0 please?

Comment: Ohh I understand it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Factorising h from both N&D to get$$=-\frac{h+2x}{x^2(x^2+2xh+h^2)}$$
$$=-\frac{h+2x}{x^2(x+h)^2}$$

Comment: But you factorised $x^2$ on the bottom? Also, when I factorised h from the top I got $h(-2x-h)$

Comment: after cancelling h we can further take x^2 common... in the denoimnator

Comment: You can also factorize the denominator $$h(x^4+2x^3h+x^2h^2)$$

Comment: i took minus sign common from the numerator... it cna be done in a single step

Comment: @Newbie101 They're the same,  $-2x-h = -(2x+h) = -(h+2x)$